# Why WsaRecvFrom do not return WSAETIMEDOUT

Tags: c++, windows, asyncsocket

I am writing the UPD client (windows) where sometimes the servers quitely drops the connections so I have used setsockopt to set the timeout for the socket but WSARecvFrom will not return WSAETIMEDOUT and gets blocked but if I use recv/WSARecv/recvfrom this works fine that is I get the error WSAETIMEDOUT after the specified timeout.

I want to use to WSARecvFrom since i am doing Asysncronous IO so i can't use use recvfrom in this case.

As per MSDN also WSARecvFrom will not return WSAETIMEDOUT so is there any other way to get the timeout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741686(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you're using async IO, you don't *need* a timeout.  Just use WSACancelAsyncRequest  as appropriate.

Comment: Inorder to use WSACancelAsyncRequest I need to run a timer and if i do not recive the result in the time then i need to call WSACancelAsyncRequest that the last option that i am looking. Still curious why WSARecFrom do not send WSAETIMEDOUT.

Comment: If you're setting the timeout using SO_RCVTIMEO, note that according to the docs this only works for *blocking* calls, not for asynchronous I/O.  And the other sort of timeout only applies to TCP, not UDP.  So I don't think WSARecvFrom is special per se, it's just that it only allows non-blocking UDP sockets, so there can't be a timeout.

Comment: As to why only blocking calls support a timeout, that is probably because a blocking call is implemented by making an asynchronous request and then calling WaitForSingleObject or a similar function.  The socket timeout becomes the timeout argument for the wait, so it is straightforward to implement.  For asynchronous I/O, the programmer can implement a timeout more easily and more efficiently than the socket library could.

Comment: But the sibling of WSARecvFrom that is WSARecv returns WSAETIMEDOUT so this is confusing me more.

Comment: Even for an overlapped UDP socket?  The documentation for WSARecv specifically says that won't happen, so yes, if you're seeing that then something is weird.